# Tables in IE do not have border when border = 0 in a css reset?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, css-tables

In my css file, I have a reset where I am setting the border:0.  This causes all tables in IE, not firefox to have no border.  Even if I set the border inline on the table, it still does not show in IE. Does anyone know the solution to this?

Part of the rest:

```
table, img
{
   border:0;
}

<table border="1">
<tr>
<td></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Border shows up in firefox, but not in IE.  Do I have to do style="border:1px solid black" in the table instead of border="1"

Comment: Any chance of a look at your css/xhtml? It might be anything from a specificity conflict to a typo.

Comment: Do I put border:none in the reset.

Comment: I created a test page, http://jsbin.com/iyato and it works fine in IE6. Are you using some other version of IE?

Comment: It does not work in IE7 or IE8

Comment: That's interesting. I don't have access to IE7 so can't test it. How about creating a class named "customtable" and set the border property to appropriate value and applying that class on your table tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want that specific table to have a border, I would just give it a class:

```
table, img
{
   border:0;
}
table.something
{
    border: solid 1px #000000;
}

<table class="something">
  <tr>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

That should work in all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a border you shouldn't set the border to 0. Try this instead:

```
table{
   border: 2px;
}
```

That should work out better.

EDIT:

If you want to do it inline, you should do

```
<table border="2px">
```

Comment: I am using border:0 because I am also using it for images

Comment: If he wants to do it inline, he should use `style="border:1px`, not the `border` attribute.  I don't know why it wasn't deprecated for tables like it was for images.  :-/

Comment: @Xaisoft: if you want to have borders on tables, but not on images, you should style them separately.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that there's no typo in your code (in the question), have you tried adding a measurement unit to the inline setting?

`<table border="1px">`

For example?

Elsewise, try using CSS to re-/activate the borders:

```
<table style="border: 1px solid #000;"> <!-- or use a stylesheet, or style block, obviously -->
```

Have you checked that you're using a standards-compliant [doctype declaration](http://www.w3.org/QA/2002/04/valid-dtd-list.html), and not lapsing into quirks-mode?

Comment: The `border` attribute only accepts pixel widths without a suffix.  (Some browsers might accept it, but I wouldn't rely on it.)

Comment: ...ever since the Standards Wars my table-fu has become weak. Upvoted, Ben, thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 0):

A couple standards-compliant ways to specify no border in css are:

border-width:0;
border-style:none;

Table elements, td elements and th elements all accept borders so a safe way to ensure no borders at all would be table, td, th {border-style:none;}.

table {border-collapse:collapse;} is a purely css way of removing spacing between cells

Check out w3schools.com or w3.org for standards-compliant css tips

Answer (score 0):

Your example table has nothing in it. IE decides it has no content and so does not show the "border="1" attribute.

Reset with

```
table {
  border:none;
}
```

Then use:

```
<table style="border:solid 1px #000;>
<tr><td>x</td></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score -1):

have you tried

```
table {border-collapse: collapse;}
```

EDIT: wait, you're trying to get rid of the border or add it? Now I'm confused...

Comment: In my rest, I just have table and a bunch of other elements and with  margin, padding all 0, etc and border:0.  Are you saying to put border-collapse in the reset or in the inline style

Comment: I am trying to add the border. In IE, the border does not show, but in firefox, it does show.  I just wanted to let you know it works in firefox, but not IE.